# Generar PDF a partir de stream

Tags: android, pdf

Quisiera saber cómo generar un PDF a partir del response que obtengo de una petición por https, recibo un stream de esta forma:

```
%PDF-1.4\n%âãÏÓ\n3 0 obj\n<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 1314>>stream\nxÕXÍn\u001b7\u0010¾ïSðè\u001cLsH\u000e¹ë[ªØÆu\u001d5...
```

he visto ejemplos de cómo descargar el archivo a partir de un link, pero esta solución no me ayuda ya que necesito autenticar la petición, de antemano gracias.

Comment: y cual es el código???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24740228/android-download-pdf-from-url-then-open-it-with-a-pdf-reader este es uno de los ejemplos de cómo descargarlo, pero es con http y sin autenticación